# Adding a mapping script to google sheet i was added to and getting an error while it works on a test sheet that isn't shared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is my first time posting, so if this is redundant, please forgive me. But I am trying to optimize my workplace spreadsheet to automatically calculate travel time. I added the script to the sheet that was shared to me, and i keep getting the error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzVnw.png). So to test, i copied the sheet to a blank worksheet that isn't shared, and everything works. I'm guessing it's because I'm not the creator of the sheet, or the code, but I'm not sure. The code I'm using is

```
/**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, 
Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, 
IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" 
or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
    var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
    //convert to minutes and return
    return duration / 60;
  break;
case "hours":
    // get duration in seconds
    var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
    //convert to hours and return
    return duration / 60 / 60;
  break;      
case "kilometers":
  return meters / 1000;
  break;
default:
  return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }

}
```

Any help and or suggestions, or maybe a workaround would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Please post your code in the question. Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: According to the documentation `Maps Can calculate directions, but not display maps` so maybe it can't calculation distances also it's conclusive but there are restrictions on the services available to custom functions

Comment: Well like I said, the code works on sheets that I created. But it's when I'm using it on sheets that i was added to as editor, the error comes up. "internal error execution of custom function". I also tried another script and same thing. works on sheets i create, but not the one i was added to.

Comment: Try reading the [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) on custom functions yourself